# How to implement Windows Single Sign On for Tomcat in IIS

Tags: iis, tomcat, single-sign-on

How can I obtain the current Windows domain user in an application on Tomcat.

`request.getRemoteUser()` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [WAFFLE](http://dblock.github.com/waffle/). It does not need Kerberos configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has some documentation on LDAP authentication with Tomcat. I'd say take a [look at this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm).